# Probability for rolling three or four 20-sided dice (d20)

Tags: probability, dice

Each 20-sided die in this case has equal chance to land on any whole-number value 1-20.

I understand that if I aimed for *at least* one 20 from a roll of two dice: either d1 is a 20 (1/20), or d2, or both (1/(20^2)).
If if wanted to be more "strict" and aim for *just one* 20 between them, I combine the chances for *either* and subtract the chance for *both*.

I managed to apply this "formula" to a chance to get any value on the die in a 2d20 roll situation.

**What I struggle with** is the following situations: *rolling 3d20* aiming for just one "success", and *rolling 4d20* aiming for just one "success".

Please help me understand the logic for both the 3d20 and the 4d20 situations, let's say regarding 20 as a success.

Then please show me how you turn this into a "formula" for any d20 value as a success.

*For example, when I tried a formula for 3d20*:
3 times P(success per die) - 3 times P(success on 2/3 dice with no regard to die #3) - P(success on all 3).

This seemed fine until I reached values of 11 and lower, where the chances dropped instead of increased.

Thanks a lot in advance, please help me understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever done event probabilities or the binomial distribution? Your first situation of 2 dice perfectly describes an event space.

Let $Pr(A) = d1$ getting a $20$ $Pr(B) = d2$ getting a $20$. $Pr(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{20} \times \frac{1}{20}$ as the events are **independent**, just like you said. This is fine when you have 2 events but when you start get more complicated events like 3 or 4 or more (ie 3+ die), you may want to consider the binomial distribution.

The binomial distribution states for every criteria in binomially distributed event space, the probability of obtaining such a criteria is

$$Pr(X = x) = {n\choose x}({p})^x({1-p})^{n-x}$$

Lets decode this. $X$ is the success criteria (what you want to achieve) (In your case rolling a 20). Small $x$ is on how many tries do you want to achieve that success (In your case just 1 "20"). $n$ is total number of tries (In your case 4 tries as each die (assuming you have 4) can roll a 20). $p$ is the probability of success (In your case, success of rolling a 20 or ($\frac{1}{20}$))

The ${n\choose x}$ part means how many ways are there to choose $x$ items from $n$ number of items.

The $({p})^x$ denotes the probability of your event occurring with respect to total number of success chosen.

The $({1-p})^{n-x}$ denotes the probability of everything else in your sample space occurring with respect to total number of success chosen. This is key as not only does your success criteria, $X$ affect your probability but also $X'$ - everything else their is to occur can also occur.

Now putting everything in terms of your event:

In your event of you having 4 die and wanting just $1$ roll of $20$ between them. Let $X$ denote the success criteria of rolling a $20$ out of 4 die and the probability of success of rolling a $20$ is ofc $\frac{1}{20}$. We just want $X = 1$ out of the 4 die (as there is 1 "20" on each).

$Pr(X = 1) = {4\choose 1}\times(\frac{1}{20})^1\times(1-\frac{1}{20})^{4-1} \approx 0.171475$

Comment: Please review my approach to see if I understood you correctly. Let's say I roll 3d20, and a success would be defined as exactly one roll of 12 or higher (45% chance):

"n on x" part would be "3 on 1" = 3,
p^x would be 0.45^1,
the 1-p part would be (1-0.45)^(3-1) = 0.55^2.

The result I get for this calculation is around 41%, which is lower chance than when I roll 2d20 (there it's almost 70%).
Where did I fail to understand your explanation?

Comment: @PerpelTertel "a success would be defined as exactly one roll of 12 or higher (45% chance)", your changing your chance of success here (making a conditional event (this changes things)). Do you want you the die to roll a "20" only or anything between a "12 - 20" ?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. A success regarding a specific d20 value (X), would be a result of X or higher - on one of the dice rolled. [I know that it can be on 2/3 or even 3/3 dice, but that's "more than the minimum chance" for my needs]

Comment: So you want you success criteria being $X >= y$ where y is an arbitrary value (suppose $12$) and therefore your success to roll any value from $12$ to $20$ on your die and your event, being, rolling 1 "$20$" .